# Cannot get user status in Discord.JS V14

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I was trying to get the status of a specific user using DiscordJS

I tried this:

```js
client.on("ready", async (client) => {
  console.log(
    chalk.bgGreen("CLIENT"),
    chalk.cyanBright(`${client.user.displayName} is ready`)
  );
  const guildId = "1151374436340088852";
  const memberId = "1098103731972747425";
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);
  const member = guild.members.cache.get(memberId);

  const status = member.presence.status;
  sMap.set("status", status);
});
```

But it is returning:

```
  const status = member.presence.status;
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')
```

How can I actually get the status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to docs, `presence` can be null. You should handle this case accordingly.
Docs: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guildmember-presence

You can set some default value if it is `null`. For example:

```
const status = member.presence?.status ?? 'offline';
```